# Not able to navigate when token is null in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to navigate to /login in React Js, but I get the following error.

> You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your
> component is first rendered.

Main.js

```
function Main() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  if (token == null) {
    navigate("/login");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {token && <AdminHeader />}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />}></Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
        <Route path="/admin/" element={token && <AdminPage />}>
          <Route path="/admin/add-post" element={token && <AddPost />}></Route>
          <Route
            path="/admin/update-post"
            element={token && <UpdatePost />}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            path="/admin/add-country"
            element={token && <AddCountry />}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            path="/admin/post-list"
            element={token && <ListPost />}
          ></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Can anyone figure out where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't issue a raw navigation action as an unintentional side-effect in the body of a component. The `navigate` function needs to be invoked in a `useEffect` hook callback or regular callback.

This said however, I see a potential issue with the way you are conditionally rendering the routed content on the `element` prop of the `Route` components. It seems you are effectively trying to protect routes. In this case you should create a component to handle this and render special auth layout routes.

Note that the `Navigate` component is used instead of the `navigate` function as a side-effect.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthLayout = () => {
  cost location = useLocation();

  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  return token
    ? <Outlet />
    : (
      <Navigate
        to="/login"
        replace
        state={{ from: location }} // pass current location to redirect back
      />
    );
};
```

...

```
function Main() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  
  return (
    <div>
      {token && <AdminHeader />}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
          <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminPage />}>
            <Route path="add-post" element={<AddPost />} />
            <Route path="update-post" element={<UpdatePost />} />
            <Route path="add-country" element={<AddCountry />} />
            <Route path="post-list" element={<ListPost />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `useEffect` hook to navigate into your login page after component rendered for first time:

```js
function Main() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token == null) {
      navigate("/login");
    }
  }, [navigate, token]);

  return (
    <div>
      {token && <AdminHeader />}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />}></Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
        <Route path="/admin/" element={token && <AdminPage />}>
          <Route path="/admin/add-post" element={token && <AddPost />}></Route>
          <Route
            path="/admin/update-post"
            element={token && <UpdatePost />}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            path="/admin/add-country"
            element={token && <AddCountry />}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            path="/admin/post-list"
            element={token && <ListPost />}
          ></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```